# How do I use loops and async/await with Gulp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, async-await, gulp

I'm building a website with 11ty and, using Gulp, I'm trying to **download** some images from URL stored in an array and **then do other things** to them when the download is complete.

My understanding of async/await and Promises is quite basic and I just can't get this to work in the order I want it to.

Here's my Gulp task:

```
const {dest, gulp} = require("gulp");
const download = require("gulp-download");

arr = [
    // Some images' URLs
]

const promises = () => {

    function first(){

        for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            download(arr[i])
            .pipe(dest("src/images/promises/"));
            console.log(i);
        }

    }

    async function second() {
        await first();
        console.log('--- ON TO THE NEXT TASK ---');
        // Code for the next task would go here
    }

    second();

}

module.exports = promises;
```

The idea is that the loop in `first()` goes brrrr and then, when it's done, the code in `second()` gets executed. In reality, here's what i see in the terminal:

```
[11:12:45] Using gulpfile ~/[...]/gulpfile.js
[11:12:45] Starting 'promises'...
0
1
2
--- ON TO THE NEXT TASK ---
[gulp] Downloading https://[...]/image1.jpg...[gulp] Downloading https://[...]/image2.jpg...[gulp] Downloading https://[...]/image3.jpg... 0.3076966000480284% 0.05975911747906604% 0.05752515731185281% Done
 0.26226932127136454% 0.2759738467431939% Done
 Done
[11:12:49] The following tasks did not complete: promises
[11:12:49] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

Looks like my `second()` function gets executed before the downloads are complete. And then there's "signal async completion" that I'm not sure how to deal with, and if it has to do something with the main issue.

Comment: `first` doesn't return a promise, and it's not an async function, so `await first()` doesn't actually wait for anything

Comment: to turn gulp-download into a promise, try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-stream-to-promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, `first` doesn't return a promise, and it's not an async function, so await first() doesn't actually wait for anything.

Now, I don't actually know what `download([i])` specifically does, BUT if it returns a promise, you can do something like this:

```
function first(){
        const promises = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            const promise = download(arr[i])
                               .pipe(dest("src/images/promises/"));
            promises.push(promise);
        }
        return Promise.all(promises);
    }
```

That way, `first()` does return a promise, and `await first()` waits for the `Promise.all` to complete.

If `download().pipe()` DOESN'T return a promise of some sort, then... you're going to have to figure out how to make it do that...

---

edit

looks like there's a library to make `gulp-download` into a promise, so you probably want to use that:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-stream-to-promise

Here's how that might look:

```
function first(){
        const promises = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            const stream = download(arr[i])
                               .pipe(dest("src/images/promises/"));
            const promise = gulpStreamToPromise(stream);
            promises.push(promise);
        }
        return Promise.all(promises);
    }
```